# One to one Relationship display in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am having trouble displaying the one to one relationships in grails. I have used grails create-domain-class and grails create-all in the grails > command line and am using the h2 database.

```
class Employee {

int id
String firstName
String lastName
Country country
Classification classification




static constraints = {
  }
} 


package com.app

class Country {

int id
String countryName
static belongsTo = [employee: Employee]



static constraints = {
  }
}



package com.app

class Classification {

int id
String classificationText

static belongsTo = [employee:Employee]

static constraints = {
   }
}
```

I have my domain classes as above and after using a create-all on com.app.Employee it generates the rest points and I use run-app to start the service. When displaying in localhost:8080 I cannot edit the Country and Classification class variables to use countryName and Classification Text. It just displays these empty scroll boxes. Does anyone know a fix?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Classification and a Country first. Then when you create the Employee in the Country and Classification fields you have to put the Country and Classification ids.

So, you create a Country, it is stored and have an id, then you create a Cassification, it is stored and have another id, finally you create the Employee and use the ids created to map it with the Country and the Classification.